# How can I decrypt the cipher encrypt from Java using CryptoJS like this

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, aes, cryptojs

First, I’m so sorry that my English is not good that may make u confusing what am I say.But I really hope that someone can help me……

Here is my Java code to encrypt the cipher:

```
public static String decryptByAES_CBC(String data, String key) {
    try {
        byte[] decryptFrom = convertHexStringToBytes(data);

        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
        SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");

        String iv = new StringBuffer(key).reverse().toString();
        IvParameterSpec ivSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv.getBytes());

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivSpec);

        byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(decryptFrom);
        return new String(original);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LogUtil.exception(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Now begin to encrypt in Java:

```
EncryptionUtil.encryptByAES_CBC("whywhywhywhywhywhy", "9999999999999999”);
```

Then got the result:

```
030f7c7d57e82c6fb7d3066363e59c9dd6de7daa486146857552d31403a7cc71
```

And I can get the same encrypt result in CryptoJS,here is my CryptoJS code:

```
encodeByAES_CBC(data, key) {
    return CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
            iv : CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
            mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding : CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
        }).ciphertext.toString();
},
decodeByAES_CBC(data, key) {
    return CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(data, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
            iv : CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
            mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
            padding : CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
        }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
}
```

Here is the question which confusing me:
For example:

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase");
var decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(encrypted, "Secret Passphrase");
console.log(decrypted.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); \\ The output is "Message"
```

The output is right because the param `encrypted` is a `CipherParams` type.

But I don’t know how can I get the right decrypted answer when I only have the ciphertext just like `030f7c7d57e82c6fb7d3066363e59c9dd6de7daa486146857552d31403a7cc71` which I get from server and the key `9999999999999999` .

Em……That’s all,and hope what I say is clear enough……

Comment: You have to pass the data in such a way that CryptoJS has implicitly or explicitly a `CipherParams` object available during decryption. You can pass the data explicitly as a `CipherParams` object (encapsulating the ciphertext and if a passphrase was used the salt). Or you can pass the Data in OpenSSL format, then CryptoJS will perform an implicit conversion.

Comment: @Topaco THX!U are right! What confuse me is when I don’t have the salt, how can the decrypt work.But it may don’t need the salt,because i use the padding mode:  `CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding` .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to do.

```
var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message", "Secret Passphrase”);

CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
            ciphertext: encrypted.ciphertext,
            salt: encrypted.salt
        }).toString(CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL),key).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8)); \\ The output also is "Message"
```

And in my Java code, because I use the Noppading(Caution: Noppading in Java = Zeropadding in CryptoJS!!!This trouble me lots of time…),so it is not need to add salt in CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create().

So if I can only get the cipher and the key from Java encrypt.I can decrypt in

```
CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(CryptoJS.lib.CipherParams.create({
        ciphertext: CryptoJS.enc.Hex.parse(data)
      }).toString(CryptoJS.format.OpenSSL), CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
        iv : CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key),
        mode : CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
        padding : CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding
    }).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
```

Still hope what I am say is clear enough to this question.And I hope it can help anyone else...

Comment: The salt is needed for decryption if it was generated during the associated encryption, which is the case when key (and IV) are derived from a passphrase, see [_The Cipher Input_](https://cryptojs.gitbook.io/docs/#the-cipher-input).

Comment: [Padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Padding_(cryptography)) has nothing to do with the salt. The counterpart to Java's `NoPadding` is `CryptoJS.pad.NoPadding` (`ZeroPadding` probably works for you because CryptoJS's `ZeroPadding` doesn't pad if the plaintext length is already an integer multiple of the block size).

Comment: @Topaco OK!I will learn more about why it can decrypt successful without salt when I use `CryptoJS.pad.ZeroPadding`.THX!